# HLSL ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource Error

Tags: c++, directx, buffer, constants, hlsl

Ok,

so i have a shader which expects two constant buffers, but when I use

```
ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource
```

And I set the SubResource to 1 (the second buffer), then I'm warned (error...):

```
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::UpdateSubresource: DstSubresource index (1) out of range, must be less than 1. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #287: UPDATESUBRESOURCE_INVALIDDESTINATIONSUBRESOURCE ]
```

I understand the error, but just not why it appears, i.e. why it happens?

Thank You

Comment: Can you show a piece of source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SubResource is designed for TextureArrays/Mipmaps, so you can for example read/write a specific mip slice. In case of buffers the SubResource is always zero (since it's just more or less raw data).

You can find some info about SubResources [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

So you can use 0 to update each of your constant buffer, then you need to assign each constant buffer to the shader slot, using PSSetConstantBuffers (and for each stage where it is needed), then choose the startslot accordingly (which should match the register number in your shader).